# Special orthogonal group is a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I work on a problem where I'm asked to proove that $SO(n)$ is a submanifold of $R^{n^2}$.
If done that by defining a function $f(A)=AA^T-Id$ which satisfies the condition that $f^{-1}(0)=SO(n)$.
I procceded by checking that $df(B)=B*A^T+A*B^T$ is surjective as I can find for every $C$ which is element of $Im(f)$ an $B=$$1/2$  $CA$ which 'hits' C. So it seems to me that everything necessary is done, but I haven't used the fact that $detA=1$ for every element of $SO(n)$. 
Could someone explain to me wether I've done everything correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your argument is fine: you are using that fibers over regular values of smooth maps are submanifolds. The determinant $1$ condition is built into the definition of the map $f$.

Comment: Sorry but (maybe due to my poor english) I didn't understand why the $det=1$ condition is built in. Could you explain it for dummies once again?

Comment: Is it because I know, that $det(AA^T)=$ $1$ or $-1$ if $AA^T=Id$?

Comment: Oh...sorry. There is an error in the statement: $f^{-1}(0) = O(n)$, not $SO(n)$. So you've shown that $O(n)=SO(n) \sqcup \epsilon SO(n)$ is smooth. But a $X$ is a manifold if and only if its connected components are manifolds, so $SO(n)$ is. My mistake.

Comment: So yes to your second comment.